# Array access on a Getter that returns a pointer, is that bad practice?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, getter-setter

Imagine the following scenario:

```
class A 
{
    int a[50];
    int* GetAPtr() { return a; };
};
...
A b;
if(b.GetAPtr()[22] == SOME_RANDOM_DEFINE) do_this_and_that();
```

Is this kind of access considered bad practice? b.GetAPtr()[22]

To clarify my situation:
1. I cannot use new/malloc in this case, the array muste be static 
2. This is meant to encapsulate older C code that uses multiple arrays where this comes extremly handy 
3. I know that returning a pointer can possibly return a NULL pointer, we do not talk about that issue here

Comment: Yes because it completely defeats the point of making `a` a private member in the first place.

Comment: that IS a good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need such const expression you could make it into a function:

```
class A 
{
    int a[50];
    bool check_this_and_that() { return a[22] == SOME_RANDOM_DEFINE; };
};
...
A b;
if(b.check_this_and_that()) do_this_and_that();
```

magic numbers are bad in general but inside a class logic it's more forgiveable and outsiders don't have to see this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is bad practice, because you have no way of knowing how long the array is. You could follow the idiomatic standard library approach and return `begin` and `end` pointers, pointing to the first and one-past-last elements.

```
class A 
{
    int a[50];
    int* begin() { return &a[0]; };
    int* end() { return &a[50]; };
    const int* begin() const { return &a[0]; };
    const int* end() const { return &a[50]; };
    size_t size() const { return 50; } // this could be handy too
};
```

As well as giving you the tools to iterate over the elements like you would over a standard library container, this allows you to check whether any pointer to an element of the array is `< v.end()`. For example

```
it* it = b.begin() + 22;
if(it < b.end() && *it == SOME_RANDOM_DEFINE) do_this_and_that();
```

This makes it trivial to use standard library algorithms:

```
A b;
// fill with increasing numbers
std::iota(b.begin(), b.end());
// sort in descending order
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());

// C++11 range based for loop
for (auto i : b) 
  std::cout << i << " ";
std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetAPtr` is a method for accessing a private data member. Now ask yourself what are the advantages of `b.GetAPtr()[22]` over `b.a[22]`?

Encapsulating data is a good way to maintain constraints on and between data members. In your case there is at least a correlation between the `a` array and its length `50`.

Depending on the use of `A` you could build a interface providing different access patterns:

```
class A {
   int a[50];
public:
   // low level
   int atA(unsigned i) const { return a[i]; }
   // or "mid" level
   int getA(unsigned i) const { if(i >= 50) throw OutOfRange(); return a[i]; };
   // or high level
   bool checkSomething() const { return a[22] == SOME_RANDOM_DEFINE; }
};
```